# How many people put their names in the Goblet of Fire for Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

We know that the entirety of the two visiting schools (bar,  perhaps Fleur's sister) entered their names, but who from Hogwarts entered their names, for Hogwarts ([Harry doesn't count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22621/3804)) ?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Goblet_of_Fire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Goblet_of_Fire), the following individuals were named in the text (or shown in the film) as attempting to nominate themselves;

- **Angelina Johnson**, *Gryffindor* house, unsuccessful.

  > *People were cheering out in the Entrance Hall. They all swivelled around in their seats, and saw Angelina Johnson coming into the Hall, grinning in an embarrassed sort of way. A tall black girl who played Chaser on the Gryffindor Quidditch team, Angelina came over to them, sat down and said, ‘Well, I’ve done it! Just put my name in!’*
- **[Cassius](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cassius_Warrington#cite_note-0) Warrington**, *Slytherin* house, unsuccessful.

  > *‘There’s a rumour going round, Warrington got up early and put his name in,’ Dean told Harry. ‘That big bloke from Slytherin who looks like a sloth.’*
- **Unnamed Slytherin Student** (Film only)

  [image]
- **Cedric Diggory**, *Hufflepuff* house, selected as Hogwarts Champion.

  > *‘And all the Hufflepuffs are talking about Diggory,’ said Seamus contemptuously. ‘But I wouldn’t have thought he’d have wanted to risk his good looks.’*

  [image]

---

For completeness, I should mention that the following individuals also entered their names.

- **S. Fawcett**, *Ravenclaw* house, underage, unsuccessful.
- **Summers**, *Hufflepuff* house, underage, unsuccessful.
- **Fred Weasley**, *Gryffindor* house, underage, unsuccessful.
- **George Weasley**, *Gryffindor* house, underage, unsuccessful.

> *‘I did warn you,’ said a deep, amused voice, and everyone turned to
>   see Professor Dumbledore coming out of the Great Hall. He surveyed
>   Fred and George, his eyes twinkling. ‘I suggest you both go up to
>   Madam Pomfrey. She is already tending to Miss Fawcett, of Ravenclaw,
>   and Mr Summers, of Hufflepuff, both of whom decided to age themselves
>   up a little, too. Though I must say, neither of their beards is
>   anything like as fine as yours.’*

[image]

- **The Durmstrang students**, who were unsuccessful.
- **Viktor Krum**, Durmstrang Institute, selected as Durmstrang Champion.

> *‘Anyone put their name in yet?’ Ron asked a third-year girl eagerly.
>   ‘All the Durmstrang lot,’ she replied. ‘But I haven’t seen anyone from
>   Hogwarts yet.’*

[image]

[image]

- **The Beauxbatons students**, who were unsuccessful.
- **Fleur Delacour**, Beauxbatons Academy of Magic, selected as Beauxbatons Champion.

> *Madame Maxime entered the hall behind her students and organised them
>   into a line. One by one, the Beauxbatons students stepped across the
>   Age Line and dropped their slips of parchment into the blue-white
>   flames. As each name entered the fire, it turned briefly red and
>   emitted sparks.*

---

- **Barty Crouch Jr**. (as Alastor "Mad-Eye" Moody), entered as **Harry Potter**, selected as Champion of unspecified fourth school.

Comment: Just struck by a thought. What if Barty Crouch had underestimated the complexity of the Goblet of Fire? And the fourth champion had been proclaimed to be Barty Crouch Junior? Would've been somewhat awkward.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - The cup seems to spit out random names. I can't recall how it chooses the champion.

Comment: Good answer, but I was specifically interested in people who put their names in for Hogwarts.

Comment: @ancientswordrage - I've edited to place the would-be Hogwarts entrants at the top

Comment: Good edit, is have assumed the slytherin from the film was the same add in three book (despite the time difference)

Comment: @ancientswordrage - I'm tempted to ask a "Who is this?" question.

Comment: Go ahead and ask

Comment: @The Dark Lord Interesting. The Goblet of Fire constitutes a binding magical contract, but since no kind of magic can awaken the dead, and everybody believed Barty Crouch Jr to be dead, there wouldn't have been a fourth champion. In that case, Voldemort (I mean, YOU) would have tried to find another way to bring Harry to the graveyard.

Answer (score 2):

### Champion

- Cedric Diggory

> “And all the Hufflepuffs are talking about Diggory,” said Seamus
> contemptuously. “But I wouldn’t have thought he’d have wanted to risk
> his good looks.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, p. 261

- Barty Crouch Junior (on behalf of Harry Potter)

> “Karkaroff’s gone? He ran away? But then — he didn’t put my name in
> the goblet?” “No,” said Moody slowly. “No, he didn’t. It was I who did
> that.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, p. 675

### Entered

- Angelina Johnson

> People were cheering out in the entrance hall. They all swiveled
> around in their seats and saw Angelina Johnson coming into the Hall,
> grinning in an embarrassed sort of way. A tall black girl who played
> Chaser on the Gryffindor Quidditch team, Angelina came over to them,
> sat down, and said, “Well, I’ve done it! Just put my name in!”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, p. 261

- Warrington

> “There’s a rumor going around that Warrington got up early and put his
> name in,” Dean told Harry. “That big bloke from Slytherin who looks
> like a sloth.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, p. 261

### Tried and failed

- Fred Weasley
- George Weasley

> Harry watched, fascinated, as Fred pulled a slip of parchment out of
> his pocket bearing the words Fred Weasley — Hogwarts. Fred  walked
> right up to the edge of the line and stood there, rocking on his toes
> like a diver preparing for a fifty-foot drop. Then, with the eyes of
> every person in the entrance hall upon him, he took a great breath and
> stepped over the line.
>
> For a split second Harry thought it had worked — George certainly
> thought so, for he let out a yell of triumph and leapt after Fred —
> but next moment, there was a loud sizzling sound, and both twins were
> hurled out of the golden circle as though they had been thrown by an
> invisible shot-putter.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, p. 259-260

- Fawcett
- Summers

> “I did warn you,” said a deep, amused voice, and everyone turned to
> see Professor Dumbledore coming out of the Great Hall. He surveyed
> Fred and George, his eyes twinkling. “I suggest you both go up to
> Madam Pomfrey. She is already tending to Miss Fawcett, of Ravenclaw,
> and Mr. Summers, of Hufflepuff, both of whom decided to age themselves
> up a little too.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, p. 260

Comment: Good break down